# Withdraw Tokens from a contract

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-design

I'm looking for a way to withdraw tokens from a contract.
Is that possible? I know how to withdraw basic tokens like eth and bnb from a smart contract but I want to withdraw tokens from a contract.

Answer (score 1):

This works assuming your code includes the IERC20 library (this also works with BEP20 tokens ofc, they're essentially the same). It's trivial to modify it so you can withdraw only a certain amount or to another address.

```
function withdrawToken (address tokenAddress) public {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
    uint256 balance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
    token.transfer(msg.sender, balance);
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really helpful